# Can clock cycle time be different in quartus simulator and in fpga?

Tags: arm, verilog, fpga

I'm doing an assignment where I have to code parts of the ARM single-cycle processor such as the ALU, control unit and etc. All other modules, inputs are already given to me, all I have to do is write the verilog code for the blank modules given to me.

I've managed to code the modules and the timing simulation in quartus seems to be correct, as the PC goes in the order it is meant to. However, when I try to implement it on the FPGA (cyclone IV), the HEX outputs on the board (which are supposed to be the PC, already assigned before given to me) won't budge from 0.

I have no clue as in why the code works in timing simulation but not in the hardware, because from all I know, timing simulation takes propagation delay into consideration. I looked in the file given to me, not to be changed, and the RTL viewer and I found out that the clk I'm given to use is one made from modifying CLOCK_27.

The clock cycle time shown in the timing simulation is 50ns, and everything works well under that condition. However, I've touched a FPGA for the first time for this project and I'm not entirely sure what CLOCK_27 is and if it is different in the timing simulation and in the hardware.

If the clock cycle time difference is the cause of the trouble, I believe I have to shorten the propagation delay of my design. If it is not, I now have no clue.

Comment: as a general rule dont assume sims are accurate with respect to time.  then if they do end up being that then its a good thing.  there are potentially a lot of factors here that are not included in this question that can affect the quality of the sim.  sounds like you are diving in too fast, maybe slow down and bring the design up in parts, echo some signals back out on test pins to see that they are there.  the fpga vendor may have some tools for looking inside (they add logic blobs to see your logic blobs, so you are adding more logic and risk of course).

Comment: sounds like basic fpga debug stuff thus far.

Answer (score 0):

You say that the timing simulation seems to be correct. Did you check the simulation results before and after synthesis? If not, I would suggest to do that. In post synthesis simulation you actually check that the timings are met. You can get some information about the difference before and after synthesis [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/148578/what-is-the-purpose-of-pre-synthesis-simulation)

Hope this helps.